# python global variable keep changes while I didn't do anyting

Tags: python, function, variables, memory

```
def up(board1):
 board4 = board1
 for i in range(4):
   for j in range(4):
     if board4[i][j] != 0:
         around = around_list[i][j]
         if around == -2:
            pass
         elif around[0] == -1:
            pass
         elif around[0] == board4[i][j]:
            print('a',board)
            board4[i-1][j] = around[0] * 2
            print('b',board)
            board4[i][j] = 0
         elif  around[0] ==0:
            board4[i-1][j] = board4[i][j]
            board4[i][j] = 0      
 return board4
```

this is the code, and the problem is that in the code I have been changing the values of board4 but it changes board4 but also board which is a global variable defined by outside of the function.